# I want ideas to trace which app is rebooting my android

Tags: reboot

Some process is rebooting my phone every time it connects to Wi-Fi. I thought of connecting it to the PC and do an `strace` in init or zygote or the system server, but I don't know what to look for in this traces.

Can you guys suggest some ideas or explain which are the system calls used to reboot/shutdown the Linux kernel?

I just did a logcat and got the result below. If you guys do a ctrl+F there is a "reboot" in the middle of the text:

```
05-22 03:47:08.204 27581 27581 W MtkCam/HalSensorList: [impConstructStaticMetadata_by_SymbolName] constructCustStaticMetadata_PROJECT_SCALER_COMMON not found
05-22 03:47:08.204 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.WAKE_LOCK in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #65
05-22 03:47:08.204 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.VIBRATE in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #67
05-22 03:47:08.204 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.REBOOT in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #69
05-22 03:47:08.204 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #70
05-22 03:47:08.204 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.VIBRATE in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #73
05-22 03:47:08.204 27581 27581 W MtkCam/HalSensorList: [impConstructStaticMetadata_by_SymbolName] constructCustStaticMetadata_PROJECT_FEATURE_SENSOR_DRVNAME_S5K5E3YX_MIPI_RAW not found
05-22 03:47:08.204 27581 27581 W MtkCam/HalSensorList: [impConstructStaticMetadata_by_SymbolName] constructCustStaticMetadata_PROJECT_FEATURE_COMMON not found
05-22 03:47:08.204 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #77
05-22 03:47:08.204 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #78
05-22 03:47:08.214 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #80
05-22 03:47:08.214 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.DEVICE_POWER in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #84
05-22 03:47:08.214 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #85
05-22 03:47:08.214 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.VIBRATE in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #88
05-22 03:47:08.214 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #90
05-22 03:47:08.214 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.WAKE_LOCK in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #91
05-22 03:47:08.214 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.DEVICE_POWER in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #92
05-22 03:47:08.214 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #93
05-22 03:47:08.214 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #94
05-22 03:47:08.214 27679 27711 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in package: com.sec.android.app.factorykeystring at: Binary XML file line #95
05-22 03:47:08.214 27581 27581 W MtkCam/HalSensorList: [impConstructStaticMetadata_by_SymbolName] constructCustStaticMetadata_PROJECT_CAMERA_SENSOR_DRVNAME_S5K5E3YX_MIPI_RAW not found
05-22 03:47:08.214 27581 27581 W MtkCam/HalSensorList: [impConstructStaticMetadata_by_SymbolName] constructCustStaticMetadata_PROJECT_CAMERA_COMMON not found
05-22 03:47:08.214 27581 27581 W MtkCam/HalSensorList: [impConstructStaticMetadata_by_SymbolName] constructCustStaticMetadata_PROJECT_REQUEST_SENSOR_DRVNAME_S5K5E3YX_MIPI_RAW not found
05-22 03:47:08.214 27581 27581 W MtkCam/HalSensorList: [impConstructStaticMetadata_by_SymbolName] constructCustStaticMetadata_PROJECT_REQUEST_COMMON not found
05-22 03:47:08.214 27679 27710 D PackagePrefetcher: put: /system/priv-app/EasyLauncher2_Zero
05-22 03:47:08.214 27581 27581 D SeninfDrvImp: [setMclk1][setTg1PhaseCounter] pcEn(0) clkPol(0) CamPll(0x0) mMclk1User(0)
05-22 03:47:08.214 27679 27713 D PackagePrefetcher: put: /system/priv-app/DeviceTest
05-22 03:47:08.214 27581 27581 D SeninfDrvImp: [setMclk2][setTg2PhaseCounter] pcEn(0) clkPol(0) CamPll(0x0) mMclk2User(0)
05-22 03:47:08.214 27581 27581 D SeninfDrvImp: [uninit][uninit]: 1 
05-22 03:47:08.214 27581 27581 D SeninfDrvImp: [uninit][uninit]: 0, mfd(12)
```

I'll try another logcat, but from android terminal so it will stop when the system shut down

Comment: if you simply do what you outline above the log you can view on the PC could give you enough clues ... please update your question with a paste of suspect log entries

Comment: Have you tried [tag:logcat]?

Comment: posted a raw adb logcat in the question

Comment: Regular apps can't reboot your device. If it is related to Wifi most likely a kernel driver is crashing. After reboot check the last kernel log in `/proc/last_kmsg`

Comment: I will, Robert. Thanks, do keep in mind my phone is rooted and there is a payload in it